# Transition between two colours on mouse move with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If the left half of the screen is a specific rgb value, and the right is another, how would one smoothly transition **depending on mouse position** between those two on mousemove?

So that when the mouse in at the far left, it's one colour, and far right it's the other. In the middle it would be the half way point.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BrZjJ/ - But based on set colours, not arbitrary ones.

```js
var $el = $('div');

var p_x, p_y, 
    window_width = window.innerWidth, 
    window_height = window.innerHeight;

var m = {
        moving_left: false,
        moving_up: false,
        last_x: 0,
        last_y: 0,
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };

var colors = {
        orange: { r: 238, g: 119, b: 0 },
        blue: { r: 40, g: 203, b: 215 }
    };

$el.on('mousemove', function(e){
    m.x = e.pageX;
    m.y = e.pageY;

    m.moving_left   = (m.x < m.last_x) ? true : false;
    m.moving_up     = (m.y < m.last_y) ? true : false;

    m.last_x = m.x;
    m.last_y = m.y;

});

function animateBackground() {
    p_width     = m.x / window_width;
    p_height    = m.y / window_height;

    p_x = p_width.toFixed(2);
    p_y = p_height.toFixed(2);

    switch(true) {
        // top left
        case p_x <= 0.5 && p_y <= 0.5:
            fr = colors.orange.r; 
            fg = colors.orange.g; 
            fb = colors.orange.b;
            break;

        // bottom right
        default:
            fr = colors.blue.r; 
            fg = colors.blue.g; 
            fb = colors.blue.b;
            break;
    }

    $el.css({
        backgroundColor: 'rgb('+fr+', '+fg+', '+fb+')'
    });

  requestAnimationFrame(animateBackground);

}

requestAnimationFrame(animateBackground);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o32juay5/

I'm using something similar to the above, (except using 4 colours on four corners, but for simplicity...). I just can't work out in my head how to transition between two colours...

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not using CSS transition?

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully it's clearer. It should change colour depending on the position of the mouse, so that it would be some degree of colour between the two when you're not on the far left or far right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate the colors mathematically according to the mouse position.

For each of the R, G, B values: Take values for the two colors, determine the range between them, select a position inside that range according to the mouse position, and combine them into a `background-color` to be used in CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/kbpyxxcn/6/

If you want to use this method with *four colors*, your calculations will become more complicated, unless you also define a color for the center.

Comment: Yeah that's similar to what I've been doing, but do you see how it goes from black to red instead of red to orange? That's the bit I'm struggling with.

Comment: I improved the fiddle to use all three colors. The min/max variable names are a bit misleading now, should be something like orange/green.

Comment: Ah that's looking a lot like what I'm looking for! :) Thanks. I'll have a tinker with it then.

Answer (score 1):

Add the CSS property `transition` and it works:

https://jsfiddle.net/o32juay5/2/

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -ms-transition: background-color 1s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

If you make it with javascript the performance will be less than this css property.

Comment: Sorry, have updated the question. In that case it would change from one to the other (which answered original) but it doesn't change depending on position of the mouse. See edit for more info.

Comment: Are you sure that's not working? If you enter in the jsfiddle I've been attached you can check the transition moving mouse at the top or at the bottom of the result page. In bottom it changes to blue. In top it changes to orange. All with transition.

Comment: No, you're right it is working, but it's not working in the way I'm looking for. I want something like this, http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BrZjJ/, but between two colours, not arbitrary ones.

Comment: I think he needs to have different color on different mouse cursor positions... Maybe you have to read his question again

Comment: You need to do a calculation to work out the RGB values **edit**: You need to work out the difference between the two values, then a fraction of this based on the mouse position, then add to the first color value.

Comment: @JamieC There are some JavaScript libraries (plugin) for that

Comment: Sorry for that, I don't know right now how to achieve that. I will research about this.